# Regular expression, need to stop in last regognition

Tags: regex

i have created this regular expression

```
((char) ([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[,]?([=]?[']?[a-zA-Z0-9.]*?['])?([,]|;))|((int|float) ([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[,]?([=]?[a-zA-Z0-9.]*)?([,]|;))
```

it is supposed to recognise variables of type:

```
int a, int a=1, char b, char b='1';
```

the problem is that when I type

```
int a=1,
```

it is recoginsed as true. Is there a way that the , symbol is not accepted for the last regognition or any other way to solve? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tested this one instead:

```
(([,]?\s*)(((char)\s([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)([=]?[']?[a-zA-Z0-9.]*?[']?))|((int|float) ([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)([=]?[a-zA-Z0-9.]*)?)))*[;]
```

This matches the whole definition line expecting a semicolon in the end.

If you want to match each definition in code, you can use named-groups in the body of your regular expression definition. I don't know which programming language you're using, so I can't help more on named groups.